# How to match the position of the clicked button and its modal dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, dialog, modal-dialog, position

I'm really new to this and have never tried to create modal dialogs before. I need to make a modal dialog appear when a buttons is clicked. The code:

```
function onButtonClick(e, data) {
    switch (data.name) {
    case "tree":
        window.location.href = "familytreeprocess.php?tree=" + data.context.id;
        break;

    case "edit":
        jQuery("#divdeps").dialog({
        autoOpen: true,
        modal: true,
        closeOnEscape: true,
        draggable: false,
        resizable: false,
        width: 415,
        height: 175
        });
        break;                              
    }
}
```

It works fine. However, I would like the dialog to appear next to the button clicked, to the left of the button to be exact. How can I find the position of the currently clicked button and make the dialog to adjust to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to jQuery's [documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#option-position), you can provide an Array containing the dialog position.

Comment: Yes, I know that but I'm not sure how can I find the position of the clicked button in the first place. There are more than one button for each chart item. This is actually a chart and each item has the 'edit' button.

Comment: This works and it is good enough but it would be better if the dialog appeared near the button not where the mouse cursor is. In other words, I would like to find the position of the button, its height and width and then place the dialog next to it. Is there a way to do so?

Comment: Of course, using jQuery's [position](https://api.jquery.com/position/) on your button, such as `var positionX = $('#myButton').position().left` and so on